# "Exclude FTP Users From Password Expiration" : Yes Does this setting changes occur for that Business Unit or it is a global level?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, sftp

"Exclude FTP Users From Password Expiration" : Yes
Does this setting changes occur for that Business Unit or it is a global level?
Is it limited to that Business unit only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a BU specific setting. Meaning you can set it to **YES** for MID 1, while same setting in MID 2 remains **NO**.

Comment: Thank you so much Lukas

Comment: You're welcome @AshwiniBodhade . Please remember to mark this and other answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the community. You can read why this is a good practice, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).